# Не входит в phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, cloudflare

Не входит в phpmyadmin.
Пытаюсь войти, а мне cloudflare мешает пройти?
Допустим я вхожу по адресу `https://example.com/myadmin`, прохожу вход и после того как меня редиректит на `https://example.com/myadmin/` но мне выдаёт ошибку 1020
Если кому не понятно, то когда я вхожу в phpmyadmin, мне прикрывает доступ cloudflare, почему так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите подробности об Firewall event-е со страницы Security Overview